# jQuery UI - Several tabs closeable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The jQuery sample [jQuery UI Tab manipulation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation) show's an example of how to make all tabs of a control closeable. But is there any way to make only some tabs closeable and let some stay uncloseable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from the code sample you found, you just have to adapt it to use a different `tabTemplate` for uncloseable tabs (simply remove the close icon)

Comment: But how to set a template for a single tab item? This way I can only set a tempalte for _all_ items.

Comment: Just take a look at the doc... http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-tabTemplate

Comment: So I need to change the tempalte everytime I add a new tabitem via the "Add" method? Is there no possibility to initialize a tab-control with several different themed tabs?

Sorry, just don't get it...

Comment: jquery ui tabs are not "themeable" like you want, but you can make your own add tab method and do what you want. You can also extends jquery ui tabs, take a look here : http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3924

Comment: Ok, my fault... Took a deeper look into the sample, noticing that it isn't using something like a "built-in-solution" but adds the remove-logic itself.... Thank you anyway